# What is the meaning/cause of *** java.lang.instrument ASSERTION FAILED ***: "!errorOutstanding" with message transform method call failed?

Tags: java, gradle, jvm

When running my test with gradle I started getting output below on the console. This output is coming from the JVM not my code. Kotlin DSL is used to configure my gradle build.

```
*** java.lang.instrument ASSERTION FAILED ***: "!errorOutstanding" with message transform method call failed at  line: 873
*** java.lang.instrument ASSERTION FAILED ***: "!errorOutstanding" with message transform method call failed at  line: 873
*** java.lang.instrument ASSERTION FAILED ***: "!errorOutstanding" with message transform method call failed at  line: 873
*** java.lang.instrument ASSERTION FAILED ***: "!errorOutstanding" with message transform method call failed at  line: 873
```

This is happening on Java 11

```
java --version
openjdk 11.0.6 2020-01-14
OpenJDK Runtime Environment AdoptOpenJDK (build 11.0.6+10)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM AdoptOpenJDK (build 11.0.6+10, mixed mode)
```

This output is not from my code, it seems to be from the JVM. There is no filename listed previous versions of Java seemed to have a bug related to this https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8061621

[JPLISAgent.c line 873](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-jdk11u/blob/7f0d7794b7f1d113e56f3cc8acce687f8af73df3/src/java.instrument/share/native/libinstrument/JPLISAgent.c#L873) might be what is generating the message.

*UPDATE:*

I went through all my CI logs to pin down the commit that introduced this issue. Tracked it down to this code in a unit test, of a Json formatter
utility based on Jackson.

```
    // try with a circular dependencies
    Node a = new Node("a");
    Node b = new Node("b");
    a.setChild(b);
    b.setParent(a);

    assertThatExceptionOfType(JsonUtilsException.class).isThrownBy(() -> JsonUtils.toJson(a));
```

In particular the circular dependency triggers the JVM output. I guess Jackson really gets tripped up by circular dependency but I don't understand why that causes a JVM assertion error.

Questions: 
 - What is the meaning of this warning/error?
 - What is the typical cause of this error, assertion failure in the JVM?

Comment: Are you using Java8? And what version?

Comment: Java 11, updated questions.

Comment: For the folks voting this down please explain why you are voting down?

Comment: isn't there a missing part between `at` and `line: 873`?

Comment: Hmmm... Random question, are you running the tests from IDE or from terminal? And are both giving the same issue?

Comment: Could you post your unit tests? What is on line 873?

Comment: This is not being output from my unit test, I just noticed this output started appearing in a module where I have not made changes. I have upgraded some items on my classpath recently, before I roll back start the painstaking process of trying to pin down the commit that cause this I am looking to understand what the message from the JVM actually means. I have never seen this  message in 15 years of doing Java.

Comment: Hi @ams, I am using tomcat 9 and adopt open jdk 11 and seeing this error. were you able to overcome it?

Comment: Any solution for this? The exception is thrown during our unit tests and seems to cause some weird behavior.

Comment: @MichaelKemmerzell I still don't know what causes this, but for me it was caused by circular data structure that I was using to test a JSON Utils class to cause it to generate a particular exception from Jackson. Ended up finding another way of doing the same test.

Comment: @ams Ok, thanks for the follow up! The exception was caused by MockServer in our case. We gave up fixing the root cause and simply replaced the dependency.

Answer (score 11):

The message is indeed from [JPLISAgent.c:873](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-jdk11u/blob/7f0d7794b7f1d113e56f3cc8acce687f8af73df3/src/java.instrument/share/native/libinstrument/JPLISAgent.c#L873).

It means your JVM has an agent implementing `java.lang.instrument.ClassFileTransformer`, and method `transform(java.lang.Module, java.lang.ClassLoader, java.lang.String, java.lang.Class<?>, java.security.ProtectionDomain, byte[])` has thrown an exception.

In my case, I had both BlockHound and ByteBuddy (loaded by BlockHound). A `StackOverflowError` in my code triggered the loading of a new class, then both agents also threw `StackOverflowError` and didn't catch it. I created [an issue for ByteBuddy](https://github.com/raphw/byte-buddy/issues/985), but I'm starting to think only the error reporting in the JDK needs to change.

Since the source of the exception is in Java code, you can attach a debugger and set a breakpoint on thrown `StackOverflowError`. You're very likely to find a `StackOverflowError` in your code or in Jackson first, and you should fix/report that.

Answer (score 3):

Your test is generating a very large exception cause chain.

Here is some Scala code that generates a very long exception cause chain then throws it:

```scala
val iter = Iterator.from(0).map(_.toString).map(new Exception(_))
val es = iter.take(1024 * 1024).toSeq
for {
  (e0, e1) <- es.zip(es.tail)
} {
  e0.initCause(e1)
}
//es.last.initCause(es.head) //uncomment this line for extra fun
throw es.head
```

This produces the same

```
*** java.lang.instrument ASSERTION FAILED ***: "!errorOutstanding" with message transform method call failed at JPLISAgent.c line: 844
```

Edit:

I believe this is the java equivalent of the above Scala code:

```java
List<RuntimeException> es = IntStream.iterate(0, i -> i + 1)
  .mapToObj(i -> new RuntimeException("" + i))
  .limit(1024 * 1024)
  .toList();

List<RuntimeException> zipped = com.google.common.collect.Streams.zip(es.stream(), es.subList(1, es.size()).stream(), (e1, e2) -> {
  e1.initCause(e2);
  return e1;
})
  .toList();

throw es.get(0);
```

Answer (score 1):

I got this when I made a recursive call (without being aware) AND in addition, this call had a try/catch where I caught Throwable (the highest possible exception type). My interpretation is that my catch caught StackOverflowException (and further worked on that), which made the whole thing go crazy! When I ran it in the IntelliJ debugger, I couldn't really stop the thread - somehow the new threads were being made. As soon as I removed the recursive call, all was fine.

Answer (score 1):

This problem also occurs when I use spring to verify the circular dependency. My code should be the error reported in the JVM. Check your code. There must be a dead loop.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error while creating a Spring boot API. The cause of this exception seems to be Filter recursive call.

I had added a Filter and on some condition it was to redirect to some page.

```
if(request.getServletPath().startWith("/....") {
    response.sendRedirect(redirectUrl);
}
```

I forgot to add return after `sendRedirect`. Which I think created infinite threads when I ran my program on debug mode.
Simply add a `return` statement after redirect and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem and the solution was an error in the @ApiOperation response description of Swagger Annotation above the controller...

The class was different from the return ResponseEntity of the controller:

```
@ApiOperation(value = "An api description", response = **Entity.class**)
```

Comment: How does this relate to the question at all? Are you sure you targeted the right question with your answer?

Answer (score 0):

had the issue defining a field as well as

BigDecimal verkaufspreis
and
BigDecimal getVerkaufspreis ()

after removing 'BigDecimal verkaufspreis' everything was fine