# errorOutstanding" with message transform method call failed at JPLISAgent

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-test

What does this error mean while running Spring Boot Tests using 3.1.3

```
./gradlew clean test --tests FooIntegrationTest
*** java.lang.instrument ASSERTION FAILED ***: "!errorOutstanding" with message transform method call failed at src/java.instrument/share/native/libinstrument/JPLISAgent.c line: 873
*** java.lang.instrument ASSERTION FAILED ***: "!errorOutstanding" with message transform method call failed at src/java.instrument/share/native/libinstrument/JPLISAgent.c line: 873
*** java.lang.instrument ASSERTION FAILED ***: "!errorOutstanding" with message transform method call failed at src/java.instrument/share/native/libinstrument/JPLISAgent.c line: 873
*** java.lang.instrument ASSERTION FAILED ***: "!errorOutstanding" with message transform method call failed at src/java.instrument/share/native/libinstrument/JPLISAgent.c line: 873
*** java.lang.instrument ASSERTION FAILED ***: "!errorOutstanding" with message transform method call failed at src/java.instrument/share/native/libinstrument/JPLISAgent.c line: 873
*** java.lang.instrument ASSERTION FAILED ***: "!errorOutstanding" with message transform method call failed at src/java.instrument/share/native/libinstrument/JPLISAgent.c line: 873
```

Comment: isn't this a duplicate of this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60526670/what-is-the-meaning-cause-of-java-lang-instrument-assertion-failed-er

Comment: @Rationalist I guess so.  I didn't find the other one in my initial search, based on how I was searching for the "JPLISAgent.c" part of the message, which isn't in the error output from the other one.  So I'm thinking this might be a good signpost for the other as a duplicate question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the meaning/cause of \*\*\* java.lang.instrument ASSERTION FAILED \*\*\*: "!errorOutstanding" with message transform method call failed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60526670/what-is-the-meaning-cause-of-java-lang-instrument-assertion-failed-er)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means your **JVM** has an agent implementing `java.lang.instrument.ClassFileTransformer`, and method `transform(java.lang.Module, java.lang.ClassLoader, java.lang.String, java.lang.Class<?>, java.security.ProtectionDomain, byte[])` has thrown an exception.

These exception basically indeed from **JPLISAgent**. Check details [JPLISAgent](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-jdk11u/blob/7f0d7794b7f1d113e56f3cc8acce687f8af73df3/src/java.instrument/share/native/libinstrument/JPLISAgent.c#L873)